# Smalltalk: using a block as a block argument?

Tags: arguments, block, smalltalk, function-composition

Is it possible to pass a block statement as a block argument for a given depth k? For example, if k = 1, I have f(x) defined as `[x + 3]`, but if k=2, I want f(f(x)), which is `[[x + 3] + 3]`. This is for an assignment, so I am required to use a block statement. `#value:` seems to only take integers, is there a more general version of `#value:`?

EDIT: Let me be a little clearer. My function takes a range from a to b, and a depth k. The function will evaluate on a block statement. So, for `[x + 3] method: 1 to: 3 for: 2` will evaluate `[[x+3] + 3]` from 1 to 3. I can evaluate from 1 to 3 just fine whenever k = 1. I'm trying to modify the block statement `[x+3]` into `[[x+3]+3]`, and that's where I'm running into trouble. I've tried

```
tempvariable := self "where self is the block statement [x+3]"
tempvariable := tempvariable value: self
```

but I'm getting a 
`BlockClosure(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand: #adaptToNumber:andSend:` error (which is why I thought it was integer only)

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you want to do.  Where do you specify k? The value: message can take any object as a parameter, not just integers.

Comment: foo := [ :b1 | b1 value: [ 'abcd' ] ].
foo value: [ :b2 | (b2 value) , 'efgh' ]. "Print me"

Comment: The above is a contrived example of passing blocks as arguments to blocks. You can run that in your worksheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a method (you named it `#method:to:for:`)
that creates and evaluates a block based on an initial block.

As in

```
[:x | x + 3] method: 1 to: 3 for: 1.
```

becomes

```
1 to: 3 do: [:index| [:x | x + 3] value: index].
```

and evaluates `[:x | x + 3]` three times; and

```
[:x | x + 3] method: 1 to: 3 for: 2.
```

becomes

```
1 to: 3 do: [:index| [:y | ([:x | x + 3] value: y) + 3] value: index].
```

It is **not** possible to achieve this by modifying an existing block. However, we can try to solve that problem in another way.

Let's write your function and block differently:

```
function                           block                    
f(x) = x + 3                       f := [:x | x + 3]. 
     ↪ f(1) = 4                        ↪ f value: 1 "=> 4"

f₁(x) = f(x)                       f1 := [:x | f value: x].
     ↪ f₁(1) = f(1) = 4                ↪ f1 value: 1 "=> 4"

f₂(x) = f(f(x)) = f₁(f(x))         f2 := [:x | f1 value: (f value: x)].
     ↪ f₂(1) = f₁(4) = 7               ↪ f2 value: 1 "=> 7"

f₃(x) = f(f(f(x))) = f₂(f(x))      f3 := [:x | f2 value: (f value: x)].
     ↪ f₃(1) = f₂(4) = f₁(7) = 10       ↪ f3 value: 1 "=> 10"
```

For depth k, just invoke the block of k-1 on the result of the original block.

---

### Solution

So, a solution can look like

```
BlockClosure>>depth: k
    | closure |
    closure := self.
    k timesRepeat: [ | newClosure |
        newClosure := closure.
        closure := [:x | newClosure value: (self value: x)]].
    ^ closure
```

and you can invoke it like this:

```
([:x | x + 3] depth: 0) value: 1. "=> 4"
([:x | x + 3] depth: 1) value: 1. "=> 7"
([:x | x + 3] depth: 2) value: 1. "=> 10"
```

Adapt to your needs.

Comment: or ^(1 to: k) inject: self into: [:closure :ignored | [:x | closure value: (self value: x)]]